# Deleting network files, I usually get "action cannot be completed blah file is in use" error. Must wait to delete

Tags: networking, windows-server-2003, thumbs.db

I'm on Windows 7, deleting files on Windows Server 2003.

It feels like just the act of selecting the folder, and especially opening it, will put it "in use" for at least 20-30 seconds. After waiting long enough, I can delete it. It's not in use locally, unlocker can't delete it. It's in use on the network. But I can walk over to the server and delete it every time. Sometimes it deletes immediately, for example if I delete quickly after highlighting it.

I also always get the irritating confirmation about "are you sure you want to move/delete this system file or folder" (because of the thumbs.db file, of which I have to move/delete a zillion). How to disable that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your first problem...
but to get rid of the delete conformation dialog box in windows 7:Follow these easy steps to disable delete confirmation dialog box in Windows 7:

Right-click on the Recycle Bin icon on the desktop.

Select Properties from the resulting menu.

The Recycle Bin Properties dialog box will appear. Uncheck the Display delete confirmation dialog box at the bottom.

Click on the Apply and then the Ok button.

You have been successful to disable delete confirmation dialog box in Windows 7. The method to turn it on again is very simple too. Just follow the above steps and check the Display delete confirmation dialog box.

-[Link to site I got this from](http://www.computerfreetips.com/Windows-7-tips/Disable-Delete-Confirmation-Windows7.html)

Let me know if your talking about the UAC box that may popup.

Comment: Cheers, that did work. I want to credit you for the answer but I'm really hoping to figure out part 1. If nobody can answer that part, I'll select yours as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Came across this old question I posted and realized I had a better answer, after all these years, though it's still a mild annoyance.

95% of the time a file or folder becomes locked from deletion or moving because of that thumbs.db file, which windows puts into use so it can update your thumbnails for that folder. For some reason windows forgets to unlock thumbs.db when it's done. Or maybe it's never done.

Anyway, you can "goose it" by simply copying any random image into the problem folder, and/or changing the view mode of that folder to something that previews the image in a new way you don't normally use, maybe extra large icons or whatever. Once you do this, thumbs.db refreshes, and then windows miraculously unlocks it. You can then move or delete the entire folder (including the useless extra image and thumbs.db system file).

The 5% of the time this doesn't work, either another file is legitimately in use or... it's a mystery.